# MS Access: JOIN using Concatenated Field

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a query with a JOIN on a couple Fields (ID_1 & ID_2).

- ID_1 can never be Null
- ID_2 can be Null or Not Null.
- ID_1 & ID_2 in combination is Unique

My issue:  The JOIN is not producing the desired result when ID_2 is Null

Can I JOIN on the concatenation of ID_1 & ID_2 at query time?  A few feeble attempts have not helped.

I'd prefer not to create a new Index in the 2 tables as one of them does not belong to me.

Thanks for any advice.

Simplified version of my query:

```
SELECT Table1.ID_1, Table1.ID_2, Table1.Name, Table2.ID_1, Table2.ID_2, Table2.Owner
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.ID_2 = Table2.ID_2) AND (Table1.ID_1 = Table2.ID_1);
```

Using the query above, I see ID_1, ID_2 & Name from Table1, but nothing from Table2 when ID_2 is null

Sample ("Alternative") Data: :)

Table1:

```
ID_1   ID_2    Name
===========================
A001           ACME Corp
A001   B001    ACME Medical
A001   B002    ACME Pharmacy
A002           General Electric Corp
A003           Philips
```

Table2:

```
ID_1   ID_2    Owner
===========================
A001           Bob
A001   B001    Lori
A001   B002    Becky
A002           Ravi
A003           Joe
```

When I LEFT JOIN, I expect to marry the info across the 2 tables.  The issue as describe presents the following result - ONLY joining in Owner when both ID_1 and ID_2 are both non-Null (Owner = Null is not the correct result):

Joined (Incorrect Result):

```
ID_1   ID_2    Name              Owner   
=========================================
A001           ACME Corp
A001   B001    ACME Medical      Lori
A001   B002    ACME Pharmacy     Becky
A002           General Electric
A003           Philips
```

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN`. And show query so we can help.

Comment: Sample query inserted above

Comment: What if you remove the `ID_2` ON clause from `LEFT JOIN` and leave only `ID_1`?

Comment: @Parfait, there are multiple instances of same ID_1 with different ID_2.  (think ID_1 = Mfr, ID_2 = Mfr_Div, so Mfrs with many divisions will have same ID_1).

Comment: what is it you want? Please illustrate for us with data. We see no data and we don't know your true desired result. Please post a few rows of both tables with null instances and desired result.

Comment: @Parfait - I included some dummy data above to illustrate.  - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Lets go over JOINS:

**INNER JOIN** - Only displays **COMMON ROWS** between both tables. If the joined table  has NULL in the **COMMON FIELD YOUR JOINING ON**, the row is not displayed.

**LEFT JOIN** - All rows from the left table included. Non-Matched entries from the right table will have NULL

**RIGHT JOIN** - All rows from the Right Table included. Non-Matched entries from the left table will have NULL

**FULL JOIN** - All rows from left and right table included. Non-Matched entries from left and right table will have NULL.

Using a **LEFT JOIN** will give your desired result.

```
Select A.ID_1
      ,B.ID_2
From tableA A
LEFT JOIN tableB B
ON A.ID_1 = B.ID_2
```

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified.  I am using a RIGHT JOIN in this instance, but the NULL ID_2 in Table_1 & Table_2 does not act like a matched entry.

Comment: Sample query inserted above

Answer (score 0):

If you must live with the deficient table design, you might try a query like this:

```
SELECT Table1.ID_1, Table1.ID_2, Table2.OtherInfo
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON ((Table1.ID_2 = Table2.ID_2) AND (Table1.ID_1 = Table2.ID_1))
OR ((Table1.ID_1 = Table2.ID_1) AND Table1.ID_2 IS NULL AND Table2.ID_2 IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thx!   I will try this approach.  I was not sure the syntax.

Comment: Example above tweaked to fit my example throws a syntax error on JOIN operation.

Comment: The error you get is just saying that it can't represent the join in design view.  It should still work fine.

Comment: I know the design-view error well.  This is not that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following variations. Choose the easiest to maintain or most efficient type.

**Union Query**

First `SELECT` capture records with matching ids (`ID_1 = ID_2`) and second `SELECT` captures records where only `ID_1` match but `ID_2 IS NULL` in both tables.

```
SELECT t1.ID_1, t1.ID_2, t1.[Name], t2.Owner
FROM [Table1] t1 
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 AND t1.ID_2 = t2.ID_2

UNION ALL

SELECT t1.ID_1, t1.ID_2, t1.[Name], t2.Owner
FROM [Table1] t1 
INNER JOIN [Table2] t2 ON t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1
WHERE t1.ID_2 IS NULL AND t2.ID_2 IS NULL;
```

Alternatively, consider single `SELECT` statements:

**Explicit Join** *(with `OR` in `ON` clause)*

```
SELECT t1.ID_1, t1.ID_2, t1.[Name], t2.Owner
FROM [Table1] t1
INNER JOIN  [Table2] t2 ON (t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 AND t1.ID_2 = t2.ID_2)
      OR (t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 AND t1.ID_2 IS NULL AND t2.ID_2 IS NULL);
```

**Implicit Join** *(query with no explicit `JOIN`)*

```
SELECT t1.ID_1, t1.ID_2, t1.[Name], t2.Owner
FROM [Table1] t1, [Table2] t2
WHERE (t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 AND t1.ID_2 = t2.ID_2)
   OR (t1.ID_1 = t2.ID_1 AND t1.ID_2 IS NULL AND t2.ID_2 IS NULL);
```

Each above should return (but not necessarily in same order) the following output:

```
-- ID_1     ID_2    Name                    Owner
-- A001             ACME Corp               Bob
-- A001     B001    ACME Medical            Lori
-- A001     B002    ACME Pharmacy           Becky
-- A002             General Electric Corp   Ravi
-- A003             Philips                 Joe
```

Comment: Parfait, that looks good.  I am travelling this week but will confirm in my actual DB when I return.  I will post back my result.  - Thanks!